# Issue Creating Certificate Authority with OpenSSL

Tags: linux, ubuntu, openssl, ubuntu-16.04, landscape

I am attempting to generate and sign a new SSL certificate as the previous one was issued to a different domain name and is preventing login to landscape from the web. Although I am running into a strange problem in that the command:

```
sudo /usr/lib/ssl/misc/CA.pl -newca
```

Simply continues to the next blank line within the Linux shell and doesn't continue to the next step in creating the certificate authority... This was working 30 minutes ago, and the command below to generate the SSL certificate functions as expected.

```
sudo /usr/lib/ssl/misc/CA.pl -newreq-nodes
```

More information as to what it is that I am tryng to do: https://help.landscape.canonical.com/LDS/SSL

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Comment: Also see [How do you sign Certificate Signing Request with your Certification Authority](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21340898/608639) and [How to create a self-signed certificate with openssl?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10175812/608639)

Answer (score 1):

If the demoCA directory already exists then the -newca option will not overwrite it and will do nothing. This can happen if a previous call using the -newca option terminated abnormally. To get the correct behavior, delete the demoCA directory if it already exists.

- Source:  https://www.mkssoftware.com/docs/man1/openssl_CA.pl.1.asp